# Deleting a site content type in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I'm trying to delete a custom content type that I've created, but I'm getting an error when I try to do so:

The content type is in use.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.DeleteFromWeb(SPContentTypeId id, String  strName) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.Delete(SPContentTypeId id) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.Delete() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageContentTypePage.DeleteContentType() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageContentTypePage.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I have gone so far as to delete all the document libraries on this site that have even used this content type in the past after deleting items that were using it but to no avail.  There's nothing left on this site that could be using this content type, so I'm not sure why it won't let me delete it.  Is there a way to remind Sharepoint that this content type is no longer in use or some way to get rid of this content type?  I'm trying to test dynamic creation and usage of this content type.

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the a library on the parent site was using this content type still.  The important thing to note is that even though a list or library may not have an items in it, it could still be using the content type.

Thanks everyone for you responses

Answer (score 2):

You have something still using that somewhere on your site. [This article here](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/02/deleting-content-types-in-sharepoint.html) explains how to delete a content type. It also shows how to determine what is still using it using SQL Management Studio. Follow those directions and it should tell you what is still using

Comment: But like I said, this site has nothing in it at this point.  I have an empty "Documents" document library, an empty "Images" document library and a "Pages" document library containing 1 file and that's all that exists on this site.

Comment: @MusicMagi Yes but maybe something still has a hold of this, doing the SQL Management Studio trick should show you what it is, and if you cant delete it then, at least you post here more detail of what it is and we can help out more.

Comment: Ok, looks like that route may be my last viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Recycle Bins of the site and its subsites.

Comment: This seemed like it would work, but I've emptied the site and subsite recycle bin, but the problem persists.  Thanks

Comment: I assume that you are the admin for the site and thus you can see all documents, even unpublished ones? Draft documents?

Comment: Yes.  I am an administrator on the site